# Bootstrap Navbar color not changing when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the active class when the link is pressed but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/test1">TEST1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/test2">TEST2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is what I tried. But this doesn't seem to be working. `HOME` is always active no matter what I press. Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function () {
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: It worked after some link changes. I have another question, how do I make it such that the active class doesn't reset back to HOME when it goes to the other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have loaded Boostrap framwork properly (link and scripts), it works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/test1">TEST1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/test2">TEST2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have another question, how do I make it such that the active class doesn't reset back to HOME when it goes to the other pages?

Comment: You can put active class to the other li depending of the page you are in. Home.html with li active class, Test1.html with li active class, etc

Comment: Is it possible to make this navbar into its seperate html file while still maintaining that feature?

Comment: If you load other files with AJAX yes

Comment: A bit of javascript should let you identify what page you are on and move the active class from nav link to link. And the bit about having the navbar in a separate file that's where using a templating framework makes sense apart from using AJAX that is something like Jinja2 (python), Twig (PHP) or even Mustache and Handlebars (JS)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. Its working. Please check with the below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.nav > li > a').click(function () {
            $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
 li.active {
    background-color: red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="javascript:;;">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;;">TEST1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;;">TEST2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have another question, how do I make it such that the active class doesn't reset back to HOME when it goes to the other pages?